# Multi module architecture with compose navigation

Tags: android, module, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

What do I attach view models to in a modularized purely compose app?

I have a top level module called `:app`. Inside of `MainActivity.kt` I have my navigation code that looks like this:

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = BottomNavItem.Daily.route) {
    composable(BottomNavItem.Daily.route) {
        DailyWordScreen()
    }
    composable(BottomNavItem.Profile.route) {
       ProfileScreen()
    }
}
```

The `DailyWordScreen()` is a composable in its' own module called `:feature:daily` . I want the `DailyWordViewModel()` to be encapsulated in the `:feature:daily` module. I do not want `:app` to have knowledge of the `DailyWordViewModel()`. I want my composables to be testable via passing in required args.

Is the solution to have `DailyWordScreen()` to become a parent composable that will create the view model inside of this parent composable to pass view model state down into a child composable?

I feel like I need a fragment to host the view model and setup the composable inside `setContent {}`.

I'm currently doing this:

```
@Composable
fun DailyWordScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
    dailyWordViewModel: DailyWordViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    val state by dailyWordViewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) {
                dailyWordViewModel.setupGame()
            }
        }

        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
```

This is working fine for me, but is this correct practice?

Comment: Each of those screens already has its own set of ViewModels - the fact that you are using `NavHost` and `composable` is already doing that. Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on official Now In Android application, every feature module would have a navigate extension method, for example inside `BookmarkNavigation.kt`:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.bookmarksScreen(
    onTopicClick: (String) -> Unit,
    onShowSnackbar: suspend (String, String?) -> Boolean,
) {
    composable(route = bookmarksRoute) {
        BookmarksRoute(onTopicClick, onShowSnackbar)
    }
}
```

and the `BookmarksRoute`, `BookmarksViewModel` and `BookmarksScreen` would be encapsulated inside `:feature:bookmarks` by using `internal`, so all your bookmark stuffs would not be exposed to outside, except the navigation method

```
@Composable
internal fun BookmarksRoute(
    viewModel: BookmarksViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val feedState by viewModel.feedUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    BookmarksScreen(feedState = feedState)
}
```

your navigation host `:app`:

```
@Composable
fun NavHost(startDestination: String = forYouNavigationRoute) {
    val navController = appState.navController
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        bookmarksScreen() // <=== Here is the extension method
    }
}
```

For your reference: https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/feature/bookmarks/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/feature/bookmarks/navigation/BookmarksNavigation.kt